# how to remove X-Powered-By in ExpressJS

Tags: http, node.js, http-headers, express

I want to remove X-Powered-By for Security,Save Bandwidth in ExpressJS(node.js). how to do it?
it could be filter(app.use) ?

```
app.use(function(req,res,next_cb){ /* remove X-Powered-By header */ next_cb(); }
```

Answer (score 245, accepted):

The better way to do it is:

```
app.disable('x-powered-by');
```

You can also make a middleware to remove any header like so:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.removeHeader("X-Powered-By");
  next();
});
```

See more info on how to remove a header:

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_removeheader_name

Comment: This is not the desired/perfect/correct answer. See the one with the most upvotes. Cheers!

Comment: True, updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I just tested `app.disable('custom1');` And it worked fine (it removed the header from server response). But then I commented out `app.disable('custom1');` and the header appears again... Is this normal? I do no longer have the `res.header("custom1", "test");` in my code as I do no longer want that header, but it still appears...

Comment: I just tested `app.disable('custom1');` And it worked fine (it removed the header from server response). But then I commented out `app.disable('custom1');` and the header appears again... Is this normal? I do no longer have the `res.header("custom1", "test");` in my code as I do no longer want that header, but it still appears...
I also tried `res.removeHeader("custom1");` but does't work...

Comment: best practice is to disable it within express. see below answer

Answer (score 382):

Don't remove it; ask Express not to generate it in the first place:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12484642/506073

Go to your `app.js` and just after:

```
var app = express();
```

Add:

```
app.disable('x-powered-by');
```

Comment: IMO, this should be the answer - middleware is a performance hit on every request, why not just prevent the header being spawned in the first place?

Comment: One could also use `app.set('x-powered-by', false);`

Comment: This only removes temporarily custom headers once set, if I comment-out this line in my code the custom header reappears, so it is not deleted... and I need to delete it! I also tried `res.removeHeader("custom1");` but does't work...

Comment: err....it works...took it off on the client

Comment: It's not working for me. The line `app.disable('x-powered-by');` seems to have no effect whatsoever...

Comment: I reckon that is because of the page you are working have a cache. I have same problem. So, After changed some code in router i am working, 'X-Powered-By' header was removed.

Comment: When you test this, make sure, that you connect directly to your express application. i.e. I accidentally connected to the frontend-proxy which happend to also use express and has added the x-powered-by header again.

Comment: Yes, that was cache, just refresh did nothing, I had to force refresh (ctrl + maj + R)

Answer (score 9):

Middleware snippet from: [Can't get rid of header X-Powered-By:Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867199/cant-get-rid-of-header-x-powered-byexpress/13112545#13112545)

```
function customHeaders( req, res, next ){
  // Switch off the default 'X-Powered-By: Express' header
  app.disable( 'x-powered-by' );

  // OR set your own header here
  res.setHeader( 'X-Powered-By', 'Awesome App v0.0.1' );

  // .. other headers here

  next();
}

app.use( customHeaders );

// ... now your code goes here
```