# Cant disable X-Powered-By: Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I've tried using this but it didn't work: `app.disable("x-powered-by");` 
and I have read the post like this :

[how to remove X-Powered-By in ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717685/how-to-remove-x-powered-by-in-expressjs)

[Can't get rid of header X-Powered-By:Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867199/cant-get-rid-of-header-x-powered-byexpress)

> Iam using "express": "^4.16.4" as backend. in frontend iam using
>   "react": "^16.7.0" Single Page App.

**UPDATE**

express.js in port 5000
react.js in port 3000

when i try to hit this URL http://localhost:5000/api/product `x-powered-by :express` is gone.

in my react app when i try to hit API http://localhost:5000/api/product it will showing again `x-powered-by:express`.

**Every time using the API http://localhost:5000/api/product which means node.js/express server i got `x-powered-by : express`**

[image: Cant Disable X-powered-by express]

but when i try to `console.log(app);` i got this :

```
          settings:
[0]       { 'x-powered-by': false,
[0]         etag: 'weak',
[0]         'etag fn': [Function: generateETag],
[0]         env: 'development',
[0]         'query parser': 'extended',
[0]         'query parser fn': [Function: parseExtendedQueryString],
[0]         'subdomain offset': 2,
[0]         'trust proxy': false,
[0]         'trust proxy fn': [Function: trustNone],
[0]         view: [Function: View],
[0]         views: 'D:\\WEBSITE\\hammerstout_nodejs_client\\views',
[0]         'jsonp callback name': 'callback' } },
```

`'x-powered-by': false,` should this work?

**Code**

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
// import passport from 'passport';
import connection from './config/conn';
import { CategoryRoutes,ProductRoutes } from './modules';
import session  from 'express-session';
const app = express();
app.disable("x-powered-by");
console.log(app);
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
}))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use('/api/', [CategoryRoutes, ProductRoutes]);


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log(`Server running on port ! ${port}`);
    }

});
```

Comment: I was having the same issue on v4.16.*, but `app.disable("x-powered-by");` actually seems to work properly again in v4.17.1 now.

Comment: If you think you got it working, that's not because app.disable("x-powered-by"); is suddenly working in some version of Express. It' because you're looking at your app *without* the proxy. If you are using React for example and its proxy to pass API traffic, that proxy will add the header even if you've disabled it on your Express server.

Answer (score 14):

I have the same effect with my angular app. I'm using the angular proxy (which is the webpack-dev-server in the end) to access my server (avoiding CORS problems).

Responses do not contain the 'x-powered-by' header when I access the REST-API on my server (on port 3000) with postman or a browser.
Accessing the same server with my angular app (on port 4200) using the proxy shows the header.

My findings are: the webpack-dev-server uses express as a basis; so I assume that the "erroneous" header stems from the proxy server not from your server on port 3000.

Comment: I think you are spot on. That is the reason people are still seeing the header after disabling it.

Comment: Writing a unit test for 'x-powered-by' would help clarify this (another way unit tests can help).

Answer (score 6):

`app.disable("x-powered-by");` is the correct way to disable the custom header in express 4.16.4 .  Here's a working example with express 4.16.4 and node 10.14.2 :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.disable("x-powered-by");
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200);
  res.send("hello\n\n");
  res.end();
});
app.listen(9876, function() {
  console.log('ready');
});
```

running this from the command line, then calling `curl -i http://localhost:9876/` results in the following output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 7
ETag: W/"7-RYgBn9PSVn8wOBXbat/kibLuX5I"
Date: Mon, 07 Jan 2019 03:24:09 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

hello
```

Comment: It's probably the proxy in between. Check the other answer