# How do I removed X-Powered-By Express from Angula App hosted on Azure App Service

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, response-headers, x-forwarded-for

I have an angular app deployed to azure app service. it returns two X-Powered-By as part of its response headers as below

```
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: Express
```

I want both removed. I modified the web config of the angular app by adding the following and redeployed to app service

```
<customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
     </customHeaders>
```

However, this only removed the first one(X-Powered-By: ASP.NET). I am still stuck with X-Powered-By: Express.

How do I remove X-Powered-By: Express.

I have seen posts like here [how to remove X-Powered-By in ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717685/how-to-remove-x-powered-by-in-expressjs)

which wants you to add app.disable('x-powered-by'); to an app.js file.

I am still new to angular. I cant find any app.js file in my angular app and don't understand how to implement anything advised in that link

Comment: This question appears to be addressed here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717685/how-to-remove-x-powered-by-in-expressjs
Please check it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove X-Powered-By in ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717685/how-to-remove-x-powered-by-in-expressjs)

Comment: No please..those links do not seem to address my issue. they said to add app.disable('x-powered-by'); to the app.js file. my app deployed to the azure app service is an angular app and I am not sure where app.js file is in an angular app. I am still new to angular so I dont understand what they have described