# Bearer detects CWE-693 even after disabling x-powered-by header

Tags: node.js, express, static-analysis

Upon running the below command for a node.js project

```bash
bearer scan .
```

bearer detects `LOW: Security misconfiguration detected. [CWE-693]` vulnerability.

After using [this](https://docs.bearer.com/reference/rules/javascript_express_reduce_fingerprint) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717685/how-to-remove-x-powered-by-in-expressjs) article as reference, I have tried both the below mentioned approaches.

### Approach 1: disabling the header

```js
app.disable('x-powered-by');
```

### Approach 2: removing the header by middleware

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.removeHeader("X-Powered-By");
  next();
});
```

Can someone help me rectify if I am doing something wrong or is it a problem with bearer being unable to detect the fix for `CWE-693`?
The bearer version I am using is `v1.16.0`

Currently, I have skipped the rule to get around it by using

```yaml
skip-rule: ['javascript_express_reduce_fingerprint']
```

I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/Bearer/bearer/issues/1114) as well regarding the same.