# X-Powered-By: Helmet in micro service

Tags: node.js, express, microservices, helmet.js

What I want to just remove `x-powered-by` with the help of Helmet (npm package) I have microservice in node js. 
here is what I am doing.

```
import { micro, IMicroService } from "@artlife/micro";
import * as helmet from "helmet";
const service = micro();
service.expressApp.use(helmet());
```

`Helmet` default remove the `x-power-by` header but in my case, it is not doing. I have reinstalled everything and done with browser cache clearing. everything work if I do `service.expressApp.disable("x-powered-by");`. even `service.expressApp.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy())`is not working. no error in the console.

Is there any other config for `helmet` that I have to do?

if it doesn't work I have backup plan with this`service.expressApp.disable("x-powered-by");`

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867199/cant-get-rid-of-header-x-powered-byexpress

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get rid of header X-Powered-By:Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867199/cant-get-rid-of-header-x-powered-byexpress)

Comment: Nah I have already mentioned that it is not working in microservices