# remove header X-powered-by Express using @types/express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, backend, loopbackjs

I have to remove X-powered-by Express header, I found theses solution

```
app.disable('x-powered-by');
```

or

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.removeHeader("X-Powered-By");
  next();
});
```

but in this project we don't use express in a basic way, we import Express this way in multiple files

```
import {Express} from 'express'; // @types/Express
```

and then we call `Express.multer.file`

I'm new on this project and also on backend development, so how can I remove this header using this way and not the basic way ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get rid of header X-Powered-By:Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867199/cant-get-rid-of-header-x-powered-byexpress)

Comment: no because there is no const app = express() in the whole application

Comment: So what are you using? At some point you need to have that to use express, or you are using different framework?

Comment: we  use express and typescript and loopback

Comment: What is your entry file? like `main.js`

Comment: index.ts i'm using typescript not js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, the solution I found was in [loopback documentation - Express settings](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Customizing-server-configuration.html#express-settings)

I just add this to my rest config object :

```
  const config = {
    rest: {
      expressSettings: {
        'x-powered-by': false,
      },
      ...
      ...
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can still use it the "basic" way:

```
import express, { Express } from 'express';

const app: Express = express();

app.disable('x-powered-by');
```

Comment: on all files whene we import {Express} ?

Comment: @zedArt no, but at least in one file your project will be creating an Express application. Just using `Express`, the _type_, isn't enough to create a server.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove header in `sequence.ts` file like this.

```
export class MySequence extends MiddlewareSequence {
   async handle(context: RequestContext) {
      const res = context.response;
      res.removeHeader('X-Powered-By');

      await super.handle(context);
   }
}
```

or use `helmet` package for security of headers. thus remove headers telling how software is developed

Comment: I have a sequence.ts file where there is only this : export class MySequence extends MiddlewareSequence {} I add your recommendation code but how can I test it, if I run website the header is still there

Comment: When i test any endpoint in postman, i can't see this header

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone looking for the way to disable it for [tinyhttp](https://github.com/tinyhttp/tinyhttp):

```
import { App } from '@tinyhttp/app';

const app = new App({
  settings: {
    xPoweredBy: false
  }
});
```